# How to deal with unexpected values in JavaScript running in the client side?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In my project, I use angularjs for a SPA application. How is the pattern or guideline to deal with unexpected values of js variables?

For example, when the user pays, the can select "bank" or "card". In my JS function, I only manage these two values, but since it is the client side, they could inject any other value.

In these cases, I would like to open a "internal error" page or something similar, but I am not sure if it is the best solution.

Of course, final validation is done in the server, but I want to stop it as soon as possible.

Which is the common pattern used in this cases?

Comment: Have validation in both places: client-side and server-side.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb use client and server validation on all your forms.

With client validation you can give feedback to your users when a problem is detected BEFORE they send any info to the server. Saving them both time and bandwidth.

You can also avoid data sending on client when errors are present.

Why then is needed a server validation?

Because a sneaky user can bypass client validation and send bad data to your server. Ultimately, to avoid this, you will always need to check data on server side before saving it.

So... only server validation is a must, however client validation could be a great improvement for your users.

Also a little tiny advice more. 
If your form has data with a limited range of values (like in this case "bank" and "card"), usually a dropdown list is a better option than input raw text data.